# Integrating: cos(t)*(exp(cos(t)) + exp(sin(t))*cos(t))...

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate

$\cos\left(t\right)\,\left({\mathrm{e}}^{\cos\left(t\right)}+{\mathrm{e}}^{\sin\left(t\right)}\,\cos\left(t\right)\right)-\sin\left(t\right)\,\left({\mathrm{e}}^{\sin\left(t\right)}+{\mathrm{e}}^{\cos\left(t\right)}\,\sin\left(t\right)\right)+1$

(yeah, it's a long one)

My first thought was it's not computable, but solutions say it is

$I = t+{\mathrm{e}}^{\cos\left(t\right)}\,\sin\left(t\right)+{\mathrm{e}}^{\sin\left(t\right)}\,\cos\left(t\right)$

I don't really see how to get there since $\cos^2(t)\,e^{\cos(t)}$ can't be computed analytically.

Comment: The solution given is correct. Verify this, then write out all of the terms and group them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's drop the $+1$, whose effect is trivial. Now compare a rearrangement$$(\cos t-\sin^2t)e^{\cos t}+(\cos^2t-\sin t)e^{\sin t}$$with$$\frac{d}{dt}(C(t)e^{\cos t}+S(t)e^{\sin t})=(C^\prime-C\sin t)e^{\cos t}+(S^\prime+S\cos t)e^{\cos t},$$so you need to solve$$C^\prime-C\sin t=\cos t-\sin^2t,\,S^\prime+S\cos t=\cos^2t-\sin t.$$You've asked how to spot $C=\sin t,\,S=\cos t$. The phrase ["by inspection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Proof_techniques) springs to mind. Since we can't solve these ODEs with a standard technique without returning to the original problem, the most natural thing to try is identifying each squared function with the term lacking a ${}^\prime$.

Comment: Well, if you know the solutions it's easy to derive. What if u're in the dark, not seeing $\frac{d}{dt}(C(t)e^{\cos t}+S(t)e^{\sin t})$ directly? It seems hard to me to spot it by inspection.

Comment: @Leon I hope at least the fact that we'd want to use an [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) of that form is intuitive, because basically the only way to get an $e^f$  factor is by differentiating $e^f$. The hard part is "inspecting" the $C,\,S$ that make it work. Unfortunately, I don't think any other way of solving it exists.